# Problem receiving Auth0 token using .net 6 code

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, access-token, auth0

Have an issue getting the token from my .net 6 application. I am using the following sample code provided by Auth0:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://mydomain/oauth/token");
var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.Post };
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"client_id\":\"myclientid\",\"client_secret\":\"mysecret\",\"audience\":\"myaudience\",\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

but am getting a response with the following exception:

```
The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ForceAuthenticationAsync>d__175`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ReplyOnReAuthenticationAsync>d__173`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ReadAsyncInternal>d__188`1.MoveNext()
```

I have tried enabling/disabling different security protocols for TLS, but with no luck. According to found articles it has to do with the incompatible cipher suite. Am I missing any configuration for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve the problem, so just in case someone needs it, here is the code which works:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
var result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("https://mydomain/oauth/token",
            new TokenRequestDto
            {
                client_id = "myclientid",
                client_secret = "mysecret",
                audience = "myaudience",
                grant_type = "client_credentials"
            });
```